# in laravel 8 with seeding , i has this issue Target class [TableSeeder] does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

```
Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException

  Target class [Database\Seeders\CountriesTableSeeder] does not exist.

  at C:\......\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:811
    807▕
    808▕         try {
    809▕             $reflector = new ReflectionClass($concrete);
    810▕         } catch (ReflectionException $e) {
  ➜ 811▕             throw new BindingResolutionException("Target class [$concrete] does not exist.", 0, $e);
    812▕         }
    813▕
    814▕         // If the type is not instantiable, the developer is attempting to resolve
    815▕         // an abstract type such as an Interface or Abstract Class and there is

  1   C:\......\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:809
      ReflectionException::("Class Database\Seeders\CountriesTableSeeder does not exist")

  2   C:\......\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:809
      ReflectionClass::__construct("Database\Seeders\CountriesTableSeeder")
```

Comment: It can't find your seeder called `CountriesTableSeeder`. Try `composer dump-autoload -o` and then rerun. Also you should provide some code showing us how the seeder is defined, etc.

Comment: i was tried the composer dump-autoload -o command , but not working.

Answer (score 16):

For Laravel 8 you need to make the below changes to an existing project for seeding to work:

1. Add the **Database\Seeders** namespace to your **DatabaseSeeder.php** and other seeder files :

```php
<?php

namespace Database\Seeders;
```

2. Change the folder name of **`database/seeds`** to **`database/seeders`**.
3. Update **composer.json** like below:

```json
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
        "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
    }
},
```

4. Finally, run the below commands:

```sh
composer dump-autoload
php artisan db:seed
```

Comment: namespace Database\Seeders;

Add this on the top of CreateUsersSeeders.php helped me.

Comment: Great! All the best

Answer (score 15):

### From **laravel 8** Seeders and factories are now namespaced

---

To accommodate for these changes, add `Database\Seeders` namespace to your seeder classes.

```
namespace Database\Seeders;
```

*In addition, move all seeder files from previous `database/seeds` directory to `database/seeders` folder.*

---

In your case remove all lines started with `use Database\Seeders\...` 
from `DatabaseSeeder.php` file

It should solve the issue,

You can also run *dump-autoload* & fresh migration with seed,

```
composer dump-autoload

php artisan migrate:fresh --seed
```

Comment: I actually couldn't find this change in the upgrade guide, so this saved me some time, thanks

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/upgrade#seeder-factory-namespaces

Comment: Also don't forget to update composer autoload to 
"classmap": [
            "database/seeders"
        ]

Answer (score 1):

When working with new seeders we might get

> Target class [...TableSeeder] does not exist.

In my case, simply running

```
composer dump-autoload
```

did the trick

Answer (score 1):

working with laravel 8

```
change directory name database/seeds to database/seeders.
```

add namespace Database\Seeders; to seeders file.

```
namespace Database\Seeders;

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
class TableSeeder extends Seeder{
}
```

Update Compose.json file

```
"autoload": {
"psr-4": {
    "App\\": "app/",
    "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
    "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
}},
```

run in terminal

```
composer dump-autoload
php artisan db:seed --class=TableSeeder
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `using TableSeeder` at the top of the DatabaseSeeder.php file.

Comment: I tried all the methods in this thread but none of them worked for me. Then I remove the above mentioned line and it worked well for me.

Answer (score -1):

DatabaseSeeder.php

```
<?php

namespace Database\Seeders;

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model; 

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Seed the application's database.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $this->call([
            CountriesTableSeeder::class,
            ProvincesTableSeeder::class,
            RegionsTableSeeder::class,
            PermisionsTableSeeder::class,
            RolesTableSeeder::class,
            StatusTypesTableSeeder::class,
            StatusesTableSeeder::class,
            ]);
    }
}
```

CountriesTableSeeder.php

```
<?php

use App\Country;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model; 

class CountriesTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    private $numberOfCountries = 10;

    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('countries')->insert([
            ['country_name' => 'iraq'],
            ['country_name' => 'qater'],
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

After running: `composer dump:autoload`

I could just include the below code in my `DatabaseSeeder` and It would include the data from `SubsidyregimeTableSeeder`

```
$this->call([
   SubsidyregimeTableSeeder::class
]);
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I had an existing code of version 5.8 of Laravel.
So the files were duplicated in `Seeds` folder, the namespace was missing in and I had to reinstall Voyager with dummy like so :

`composer dump-autoload`

`php voyager:install --with-dummy`

fixed the namespace to `namespace Database\Seeders;` instead of `namespace Database\Seeds;`

Answer (score -1):

1. Rename directory database/seeds to database/seeders
2. Open composer.json file and change on autoload section.

"autoload": {
"psr-4": {
"App\": "app/",

```
    "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",

    "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"

}
```

}

3. Open Database Seeder file database/seeders/DatabaseSeeder.php and add namespace Database\Seeders; on top of page.
4. Open your others seeders file and add namespace Database\Seeders; to all seeders class.
5. Run composer dump-autoload and php artisan migrate:fresh --seed

Comment: These steps are all mentioned in previous answers

Answer (score -1):

Remember if you upgrade ti laravel 8 you need to change directory name **database/seeds** to **database/seeders**.

Comment: This is already mentioned in previous answers.